# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Buenas verán tengo un proyecto en monorepositorio con varios contextos (Microservicios) algunos de ellos en lenguajes diferentes.

La estructura del proyecto es así.

```
src
   Apps
      microservicio_1
      microservicio_2
        #raiz de api en python con flask
        index.py
        controllers
           controller.py
      ...........
   Context
     contexto_microservicio_1
     contexto_microservicio_2
```

En `src.Apps.microservicio_2` tengo una api con *flask* en *Python*. El problema esta en que desde esa api en en `controllers.controller.py` tengo que acceder a un archivo de `../../Context/contexto_microservicio_2/` pero al importarlo me da error ya que el directorio que reconoce *flask* como absoluto es el *microservicio_2*.

Les dejo el archivo *controller* para ver si me pueden ayudar ya que no encuentro solución:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask import Flask, make_response, jsonify, request
from src.Context.contexto_microservicio_2.archivo import metodo

class UserController(Resource):
  def main(self):
    
    id = request.environ['auth']
    year = request.form['year']

    try:
      metodo.main(id, year)
    except:
      pass
```

Error:

> from src.Contexts.contexto_microservicio_2.archivo import metodo
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

---

> **PD:** He cambiado los nombres, ya que salen nombres que no pueden salir.

Comment: Puedes poner la traza de error completa, por favor. Así nos será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Actualizado con el error, gracias y disculpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para importar modulos de python que están una o mas carpetas "atras", tendrías que usar lo siguiente:

```
#agrego el path deseado a la lista de paths
from sys import path
path.append("../../")

from src.Context.contexto_microservicio_2.archivo import metodo
```

No pude probarlo debido a que no tengo las carpetas ni entiendo exactamente lo que piensas hacer, pero aun asi espero que sirva al menos como base para que puedas avanzar.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar creando un archivo vacío llamado  `\_\_init\_\_.py` dentro de la carpeta `contexto_microservicio_2`.

Creo que el problema es que python solo permite importar paquetes, y el hecho de que una carpeta tenga el método `\_\_init\_\_.py` hace que python la reconozca como un paquete.

Comment: Si ya he probado y no funciona. El problema me dice que no src.  no es un modulo. Pero no puedo poner un archivo de __init__.py en src