# ¿Cómo importar una modulo de un directorio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría importar el modulo ui_login.py que se encuentra en el SUBPAQUETE_UI  a SUBPAQUETE_LOGIN ,exactamente dentro de Modulo_inicio.py.

---

Dentro del SUBPAQUETE_UI tengo clase generada de Pyqt5 y En SUBPAQUETE_LOGIN quiero crear un clase Login, para eso necesito importar .

Comment: En `ui_login.py` puedes poner `from ..SUBPAQUETE_LOGIN import Modulo_inicio`

Comment: Esta pregunta que respondí hace tiempo puede servir de ayuda! https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/408938/errro-al-importar-en-python-archivo-de-otro-directorio/409308#409308

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! La verdad no se si esto funcionaria pero lo único que se me ocurre es importar el modulo `ui_login.py` directamente a `Modulo_inicio.py`

Suponiendo que estas dentro de `Modulo_inicio.py`:

```
import ui_login.py
```

o si esta en otra ruta:

```
import la_ruta_donde_se_encuentra/ui_login.py
```

O tal vez estoy totalmente errado, en ese caso mil disculpas, pero no entiendo del todo como quieres importar el modulo a otro.

Quizá deberías agregar un poco mas de información a la pregunta para clarificar aun mas tu duda y que alguien mas experimentado que yo pueda ayudarte. De paso te recomiendo pasar por aquí para aprender a [formular una buena pregunta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Espero te sirva la información.

Lindo día.

P.D. te dejo información sobre [módulos en python.](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Si no estas seguro de tu respuesta, siempre puedes hacer una prueba y comentar los resultados.